# Function only executes once in for loop

Tags: javascript, html, function, for-loop

I have a function that starts a timer that can be paused. Now I want several timers to run after each other, for this I decided to use a for loop.

However, when I call the function inside the loop, even though the loop goes n (5 in this case) times, the function only executes once, while the console.log executes 5 times as intended. What am I doing wrong here?

```html
var timer = null;

const resetTimer = () => { 
  clearInterval(timer);
  timer = null;
}

function trigger (startTime, endTime, sets){
  for (let i = 0; i < sets; i++){
    myTimer(startTime, endTime, sets);
    console.log("1")
  }
}


function myTimer (startTime, endTime, sets){
        if (!timer) {
            timer = setInterval(function() { 
                display.innerHTML = hhmmss(++startTime);
                if (startTime >= endTime) {
                  resetTimer();
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
}
```

Comment: You've only got 1 `timer` variable. Once you've started the first interval timer, none of the others will start because `if (!timer)` will fail.

Answer (score 2):

Your function is called every time, but in all of the calls after the first one, `if (!timer)` is false, so it doesn't do anything.

If you want multiple timers, you'll need multiple places to store the timer handle. For instance, in a local within `myTimer`:

```
// No global `timer`

// Accept the timer to clear (no real reason for this function if all it does is `clearInterval`)
const resetTimer = (timer) => { 
    clearInterval(timer);
};

function trigger (startTime, endTime, sets){
    for (let i = 0; i < sets; i++){
        myTimer(startTime, endTime, sets);
    }
}

function myTimer(startTime, endTime, sets) {
    // There's a different `timer` for each call to `myTimer`
    const timer = setInterval(function() { 
        display.innerHTML = hhmmss(++startTime);
        if (startTime >= endTime) {
            // Pass this timer's `timer` to `resetTimer`
            resetTimer(timer);
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Could you please iterate on what you mean with multiple places to store the timer handle? 

The functionality I'm looking for is basically a timer that counts up to n, pauses, and then automatically counts up to n again. I couldn't get that to work with you answer. Thank you!

Comment: @Hubris - Every call to `myTimer` gets a new `timer` local variable (constant). So each of the multiple timers you're starting remembers its handle. When it reaches its end time, it uses that handle to clear the timer. (Clearing the timer won't restart it. There's nothing in the code to suggest you wanted *restart* the timer).

Answer (score 0):

You've used `if (!timer) {` so on the first iteration it will assign something to timer and after that nothing inside that `if` will execute again.

Comment: But aren't  I resetting timer to null with my resetTimer() function after it's done ?

Comment: Yes you are, after 1 seconds, when your loop has already completed.